# Regex get string after specific char, but only when the text starts with a specific string

Tags: regex

I have a list of values that contains various values, but I'm only interested in the number after # of those starting with XXX_

```
ABC

XXX_YYY

XXX_YYY#12235

XXX_YYY#12281

XXX_YYY#12318
```

I have tried several things but not quite hit the head of the nail :-(

```
(?<!XXX\_)#
```

and

```
(?<=XXX\_)\*\[^#\]+$ - closest but also get those without # in :-(
```

Comment: Maybe just `^XXX_.*#(\d+)$` and use what is inside the 1st group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the number after #, please find below python code and modify as per need

```
import re    
result = re.findall("(?<=#)(.*?)(?=$)",a)
print(result[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Both patterns do not take numbers into account, and will match:

- `(?<!XXX_)#` only matches a single # when not directly preceded by XXX_
- `(?<=XXX_)*[^#]+$` Optionally repeats a lookbehind assertion, and then matches 1+ chars other than # till the end of the string.

---

If there is a single # char in the string before the numbers, you can match XXX_ followed by any char except # using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) and then match # followed by capturing the digits at the end of the string in group 1.

```
XXX_[^\n#]*#(\d+)$
```

The pattern matches:

- `XXX_` Match literally
- `[^\n#]*#` Match optional chars other than # or a newline, then match `#`
- `(\d+)` Capture 1+ digits in **group 1**
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gwlv4T/1).